# Is there GTM Trigger based on HTML text on page

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I created an element visibility trigger and attached it to my tag. The element visibility trigger was based on an id. It turns out that that id was not unique. Hence the tag connected to my trigger is being triggered for behaviors I don't want the tag triggered for. However there is a unique message that appears along with this id. Is there a way I can create a trigger that fires only when this message appears on the website? Thanks!

I researched to see if there are any additional GTM triggers based on not only an id but also actual text on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use the element visibility trigger, but it's being frowned upon due to how heavy it is.

A better thing to do would be having an unrelated trigger, like a pageview, but then have a CJS value there as a condition. That CJS would do exactly that: check if the text is on the page and return the result of the check.

Comment: 1)What do you mean by "heavy"?

2) I know how to set up a pageview trigger but CJS(is this common Javascript?) And can you elaborate how I would set this condition? I'm a newbie

Comment: CJS is a Custom JavaScript variable. Heavy in how that trigger performs. It constantly checks for elements even when they have no chance to be there. It creates load that is better to be avoided. It's miniscule, really, but it will become significant if you keep allowing many instances of such load. I can help you with the code if you update your question with the html around the text that you want to fire your tag on.

Comment: I chose a different route. I decided to use two triggers(one based on event visibility and another based on the URL that loads- those 2 things should be unique enough)  and bundling them into the trigger group feature in GTM. However the tag is not firing after I added that trigger group to the tag. Here is a video outlining this. https://www.loom.com/share/6c1dbb365350468f81401c581acb1b9e . Thanks so much.

Comment: That's not how you use trigger groups and also, don't use trigger groups. They're bugged. They can only fire once per pageview. Your mistake in the vid is that you're using two triggers when you really need one. Move your condition from the pageview trigger to the event visibility trigger. A trigger can have multiple conditions. Plus, again, element visibility is to be avoided. It's pretty buggy and it slows down the site.

Comment: 1) I will not use trigger groups. Thanks for the advice 2) You mentioned an event visibility trigger. In the video, I never mentioned an event visibility trigger. I mentioned an element visibility trigger(which you recommended I avoid and I will). can you clarify what you mean by "Move your condition from the pageview trigger to the event visibility trigger"? thanks!

Comment: In the video, you have two triggers, the pageview and the event visibility. And you had them in a trigger group. If you want, you can go with the element visibility trigger, but that would be a sloppy solution. A solution nevertheless.

Comment: Gosh, this is really like a 10-minute thing to solve properly. It would be faster if I could just guide you through it and be done with it. Wanna just do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry one more question.

Are you using the term "event visibility trigger" and "element visibility trigger" interchangeably?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).